# PowerShell : args and named parameter

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, args

I have a PS script I call from a Windows shortcut. I drop on it several files or directories, and it works fine.
I would like to add some named parameters (let's call them : -Param1 and -Param2), optional, that can be used, of course, only from PowerShell Prompt.

```
param (
    [switch]$CreateShortcut
)
```

A switch parameter works.

But, if I add a string parameter :

```
param (
    [switch]$CreateShortcut,
    [string]$Param1
)
```

Of course, it does not work anymore when I call my script thru the Windows shortcut : $Param1 receive the first file.

Is there a solution ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried explicitly specifying the parameter name before the value? Something like `PowerShell Script.ps1 -CreateShortcut -Param1 "C:\path\to\file"`

Comment: _"$Param1 receive the first file."_, this is expected, a `switch` is a boolean, it can't receive anything else than that, in fact, PowerShell is attempting to solve the miss position of your parameters. Add `[parameter(Position=0)]` above your `switch` parameter and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**When you drop files/folders** on a shortcut file, their full paths are **passed *as individual, unnamed arguments*** to the shortcut's executable (script).

**PowerShell allows you to *collect* such unnamed arguments in a *single, array-valued parameter***, by declaring it as **`ValueFromRemainingArguments`**:

```
[CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false)]
param (
    [switch] $CreateShortcut,
    # Collect all unnamed arguments in this parameter:
    [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)]
    [string[]] $FilesOrFolders
)
```

- `[CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false)]` ensures that any parameters not explicitly marked with a `Position` property must be passed as *named* arguments (i.e., the argument must be preceded by the name of the target parameter, e.g. `-Path foo`).

  - This isn't necessary to support `[switch]` parameters, because they are *implicitly* named-only, but it allows you to support additional, non-`[switch]` parameters that can be bound by explicit invocation (only).
- Alternatively, if you do *not* need support for additional predeclared non-switch parameters, you can *omit* `[CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false)]` and the `$FilesOrFolders` parameter declaration and access any arguments that do not bind to predeclared parameters via the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args).

  - Generally, note that use of a `[Parameter()]` attribute on any of the predeclared parameters would make `$args` unavailable, as the presence of `[CmdletBinding()]` does.
  - The reason is that the use of either attribute makes a script or function an [*advanced*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) one, i.e., makes it *cmdlet-like*, and therefore disallows passing arguments that do not bind to declared parameters; to put it differently: `$args` is then by definition always *empty* (an empty array).
  - Advanced scripts or functions automatically gain additional features, notably support for [common parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters) such as `-Verbose`.

Comment: Thanks. Do I understand correctly that the only functional difference is that `$args` can't be used if `[CmdletBinding()` is used?

Comment: @gargoylebident, with respect to `$args`, yes, but as the answer notes, use of `[CmdletBinding()` and/or `[Parameter()]` has additional behavioral implications, due to making a script or function an advanced one (cmdlet-like).